# work-around for idle ssh sessions dropped because of "packet_write_wait: Connection to 192.168.xx.yyy port 22: Broken pipe"

Tags: ssh, connection-timeout, tcp-keepalive

here's the scenario: you ssh into a remote linux host, leave the terminal idle for a while and come back to find the connection has dropped.

You've read the suggestions about setting keep-alive on the connection, and tried it, and it still fails.

You maybe even know about screen and/or tmux but still would rather not have to reconnect so often.

Is there any way of accomplishing this?

Comment: could you explain why you gave this a minus 1 vote?  I'd like to avoid making the same mistake again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two workarounds which may be acceptable/helpful to some:

1. run emacs with the time display in the mode line.  You can run
   this in place of screen/tmux and use the built-in terminal mode
   which is surprisingly functional, and your connections will not drop
2. use something like the following when you leave your terminal

   ```
   alias keep_alive='while true; do ( sleep 60 ; date ) ; done'
   keep_alive
   ```

   then ctrl-c when you come back. It sleeps nearly all the time and in
   my experience printing the date every sixty seconds prevents the
   connection from timing out.